# Is there a good way to loop through APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

There are too many loops in this API, which is causing it to run slowly.
this data is only for year i have to run same code for **Day** **month** **week** looping same code makes the code slower.

````
// ```GRAPH CALCULATION FOR YEAR```\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
let query = '';
graph_data = '';
let startOfYear = MOMENT().startOf('year');
let monthsForYear = [];
let year = [];
// Create an array of dates representing the start of each month in the year
for (let index = 0; index <= 11; index++) {
  const add1Month = MOMENT(startOfYear)
    .add(index, 'month')
    .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.000+00:00');
  monthsForYear.push(add1Month);
}
// Get the actual amount for each month
for (let i = 0; i < monthsForYear.length; i++) {
  let j = i + 1;
  let d = await PRISMA.orders.findMany({
    where: {
      created_at: {
        gte: monthsForYear[i],
        lte:
          i === monthsForYear.length - 1 ? endOftheYear_date : monthsForYear[j],
      },
    },
    select: { actual_amount: true },
  });
  // Calculate the total actual amount for the month
  let total = 0;
  d.forEach((el) => {
    total += el.actual_amount;
  });
  year.push(total);
}

// Set the graph data to the calculated amounts
graphDataOfYear = year;
````

Comment: first change `for (let i = 0; i < monthsForYear.length; i++) {` with `const count = monthsForYear.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {`

Comment: @Anilkumar this hasn't been needed since IE8 which is 13 years old, and very much out of date and obsolete. It was also the last major browser to adopt automatically optimising loops. I don't see an indication OP is having troubles with browsers below IE8. If so, the ES6 syntax like `let` is probably a bigger issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute asynchronous statements (using `await`) in a loop, which means they are executed consecutively: The second statement starts only after the first has completed. It may be faster if you execute them in parallel.

The first loop starts all statements in parallel, then all results are `await`ed together and the total actual amounts calculated in a second loop:

```js
let statements = [];
for (let i = 0; i < monthsForYear.length; i++) {
  let j = i + 1;
  statements.push(PRISMA.orders.findMany({
    where: {
      created_at: {
        gte: monthsForYear[i],
        lte:
          i === monthsForYear.length - 1 ? endOftheYear_date : monthsForYear[j],
      },
    },
    select: { actual_amount: true },
  }));
}
for (const d of await Promise.all(statements)) {
  // Calculate the total actual amount for the month
  let total = 0;
  d.forEach((el) => {
    total += el.actual_amount;
  });
  year.push(total);
}
```

The general pattern is:

```js
let statements = [];
for (...) {
  statements.push(/* asynchronous statement without await */);
}
for (const d of await Promise.all(statements)) {
  /* d is the result of each asynchronous statement in turn */
}
```

It is very likely even faster if you can let `PRISMA` do the total actual amount calculation, because then only one number (the total actual amount) must be sent back to your Javascript code, whereas with your current code *every* order that exists in `PRISMA` is sent back for one of the months, and then again for one of the weeks, and for one of the days. But I am no `PRISMA` expert.

Comment: Thankyou @Heiko Theißen
this works fine, this only works for year if i have to do the same for day,month,week, i have to copy paste the same code will it effect my reduce my api speed.
or is there any other solution.

Comment: You can copy and paste the same pattern for day, month, week. Or you could collect all statements for year, month, week, day in _one_ array `statements` so that they are all executed in parallel.